# Hibernate @OneToOne loaded even though is lazy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.3, Spring Data and Hibernate.

I've the following entities

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Address address;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Address {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String fullAddress;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    @Version
    private Long version;    
}
```

When the following code is executed, any query related to the user repository is performed (and for me it is the expected behavior).

```
Address addressFromDb = addressRepository.findAll().get(0);
log.info("" + addressFromDb.getUser().getId());

// select address0_.id as id1_0_, address0_.full_address as full_add2_0_, address0_.version as version3_0_ from address address0_
```

but when I execute the following code, then there are multiple queries and I don't understanding why. Apparently the `FetchType.LAZY` from user to address is not honored.

```
User userFromDb = userRepository.findAll().get(0);

// select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.name as name2_4_, user0_.version as version3_4_ from user user0_
// select address0_.id as id1_0_0_, address0_.full_address as full_add2_0_0_, address0_.version as version3_0_0_ from address address0_ where address0_.id=?
```

What am I missing?

In order to be more helpful and more clear I've created the following [github repo](https://github.com/classicPintus/spring-boot-hibernate-lazy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate (or more specifically `PersistenceContext`) needs to know, whether the entity exists or not, so that it can decide, whether to provide a proxy for the entity or `null`. This does not apply for `XToMany` relationships, because the whole collection can be wrapped in a proxy and in special case it will be empty.

It is also important to point out, that `FetchType` is just a suggestion for the JPa implementation and there is no guarantee, that in every case it will be fulfilled. You can read more about `@OneToOne` [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), especially in terms of fetching strategy:

> While the unidirectional @OneToOne association can be fetched lazily, the parent-side of a bidirectional @OneToOne association is not. Even when specifying that the association is not optional and we have the FetchType.LAZY, the parent-side association behaves like a FetchType.EAGER relationship. And EAGER fetching is bad.
>
> Even if the FK is NOT NULL and the parent-side is aware about its non-nullability through the optional attribute (e.g. @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)), Hibernate still generates a secondary select statement.
>
> For every managed entity, the Persistence Context requires both the entity type and the identifier,
>   so the child identifier must be known when loading the parent entity, and the only way to find the associated post_details primary key is to execute a secondary query.
>
> Bytecode enhancement is the only viable workaround. However, it only works if the parent side is annotated with @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) and the child side is not using @MapsId.